# The account xyz@mail.com has no team with I'd xyz1234589

Tags: ios, xcode

Earlier I was using free personal team provisioning profile but I have upgraded to paid account.but when I signed in with upgraded I saw same personal team displayed instead of all the provisioning profile in apple developer account.after that I created certificate and I downloaded.I am following and reading article to solve this issue but getting below error

Now I'm getting this error:
The account xyz@mail.com has no team with xyz1234567

Please help me or show me the steps to accomplish my task.I am new bee to xcode and ios..thanks in advance

Comment: the code you are using may have a different provisioning profile in it. You need to install your provisioning profile .

Comment: Can you tell me in detail which code..?